# Proposal to drop "& Usage" from the site title

Tags: discussion

**Update 11/25: Thanks for your feedback! We're going to go ahead and drop "& Usage" from the site title.** The header image and the "official" language around the site (in the help center and about page, for example) should be updated within the next few days.

---

I'm Laura, a product manager at Stack Exchange.

I wanted to let this community know that I've started a discussion over on Meta Stack Overflow about some general guidelines for naming our sites, specifically our language sites, going forward. Feel free to [read and discuss my post over there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names).

The gist of my proposal is that "& Usage" generally makes a site name longer and more difficult to say and type without adding much, if any, meaning.

**We'd like to rename existing Stack Exchange language sites to just "X Language" and drop "& Usage" from both existing sites and any new language sites we launch in the future.**

This means the header image on the site would simply read "German Language" rather than "German Language & Usage", and all of the official documentation would drop "& Usage" as well. The site URL would not change.

We've already done this with our Italian Language site (in private beta at the time of this writing), and [they were pleased](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/why-is-this-language-stack-exchange-site-named-italian-language-while-all-oth) with the simpler name. Until now, our language sites have followed the naming convention of "X Language & Usage Stack Exchange", but why? It seemed to make sense at the time, but as we've grown, it's become clear that "& Usage" isn't really necessary. A site about a particular language is, by definition, concerned with the usage of that language — that's where all the questions come from!

Before we actually make any changes to existing sites, I wanted to hear any concerns you might have. I feel like a shorter, simpler name is a big win for everyone, but please feel free to post concerns about this particular community here, or any general concerns over on [the main MSO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good idea!

From the first day I was always wondering what value talking about a language's "Usage" could possibly add. Most of our questions are on language usage anyway, with only few questions on e.g. etymology, history, or typography. This will all be included in a label "German Language".

So I can no less than fully agree with dropping "& Usage" from our site's label.

Answer (score 4):

That's a good plan. Do it.

Actually, the additional "& Usage" might be a little confusing. Does it mean the usage of the german language or the german usage of something else? And what would this "something else" be?

Right now, the title is a little redundant, as in my opinion, the topich "usage of a language" is already included in the topich "language". It's always a good idea to reduce a title to its shortest and clearest form - as long as this does not cut anything away.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the "& Usage" as trial of additional tip that it isn't a translation service. Dropping it would leave that somehow, although it wasn't a very optimal representation.

So additionally to dropping the "& Usage" I suggest to introduce a subtitle also. This could be named for instance "usage, history and backgrounds - but no translation service".

Answer (score -4):

Drop "Language" as well, when you're on it. Just "German".

Comment: As we don't intend to be a site for German culture, travel, politics, history, or whatever, it does make sense to keep the topic narrowed on German **language**.